# How to display line numbers for code chunks in rmarkdown HTML and PDF

Tags: r, r-markdown

how do i display the line numbers of my code chunk with rmarkdown?

````
```{r}
   x <- 1:10
   y <- x^2
   plot(x,y)
```
````

and i would like the echo to be something like

```
 1  x <- 1:10
 2  y <- x^2
 3  plot(x,y)
```

Preferably like it is on Github...
Would be glad for any help

Comment: This discussion looks relevant: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/31

Comment: Thanks Thomas but unfortunatly this is not working properly i think.
Looking at their ramnathv's [example](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1161356/knitr-code-themes.pdf) you see, that there is a different indentation depending on the digits of each number: 1 is more left than 11...

Comment: @Thomas I believe this is not a duplicate: The other question only asks for `.Rnw`-files and thus LaTeX, but this question asks for a solution that also works for HTML.

Comment: It is not a duplicate since Rnw documents and Rmd are very different. However, one answer under that post actually provided the correct solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53280591/559676

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can produce two code blocks: one for the presentation and another, hidden, for execution.

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
     highlight: haddock
---

```{#numCode .R .numberLines}
x <- 1:10
y <- x^2
plot(x,y)
```

```{r results='asis', echo=FALSE}
x <- 1:10
y <- x^2
plot(x,y)
```
````

Note: If you replace pdf_document with html_document, you must provide the metadata "highlight".

Comment: Where to find detailed documentation for syntax like `{#number .R .numberLines}` ? I was only aware of the style such as `{r eval=TRUE,...}`.

Comment: @bruin It is from Pandoc User's Guide: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html

Answer (score 2):

Use the chunk option `attr.source='.numberLines'`:

````
```{r, attr.source='.numberLines'}
if (TRUE) {
  x <- 1:10
  x + 1
}
```
````

This works for HTML and PDF.

[image]