# Putting line number for R code with knitr

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave, rnw

I wonder if there is any function to put `line numbers` with `knitr` in `.Rnw`. I found [this discussion](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/31) and some documents (now removed from the web) but could not find the way to put line numbers.

Comment: To clarify, you want line numbers in the pdf output? Or in the .Rnw file?

Comment: Yes, I need line numbers in pdf output.

Comment: And you want them for every line of the document or just line numbers in the chunk output?

Comment: If you want line numbers for everything and are using Latex, then take a look at this solution: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18776

Comment: How about the solution here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/25299194/134830

Comment: Thanks @RichieCotton for your efforts. Same problem has been mentioned in the link without any solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This solution uses the LaTeX **listings** package to create line numbers. I can only get them to work by accumulating across all code chunks, but I imagine there is a similar solution that will enumerate lines only within each chunk. Here's the .Rnw source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

<<setup, echo=FALSE>>=
knit_hooks$set(source = function(x, options) {
    paste("\\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left, firstnumber=last]\n", x, 
        "\\end{lstlisting}\n", sep = "")
})
@

<<a, results='hold'>>=
1:2
3:4
5:6
@

<<b>>=
"test1"
"test2"
"test3"
@

\end{document}
```

The key parts of this are in the source hook, [which is basically copied from here](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/listings/). The `firstnumber=last` tells listings to accumulate line numbers across listings. Without it, all lines are numbered 1 because **knitr** is putting each code line in its own listing.

And here's the result:

[image]

If you want each code block to start numbering from 1, add a hook to reset the counter:

```
knit_hooks$set(reset = function(before, options, envir){
if(before){
    return("\\setcounter{lstnumber}{1}")
}
})
```

and then use `reset=TRUE` to activate the hook in each chunk you want:

```
<<a, results='hold', reset=TRUE>>=
1:2
3:4
@
```

Comment: (+1): This is great @Thomas. Would be nice if line numbers change within each R Chunk.

Comment: This works fine. But it is not getting the code (font) color as with original 'knitrout'. Any solution for that.

Comment: @MYaseen208 You should be able to add `language=R` to the listings options (i.e., where it says `numbers=left, firstnumber=last`). You my have to go through the [listings manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf) to understand how to gain fine control over the highlighting.

Comment: Any chance of customizing the rendering of the line numbers (i.e. lower font size)? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When using knitr with Lyx or Latex, I've found it helpful to add the lineno package to the document pre-amble and then to enclose the chunk with the `\internallinenumbers \resetlinenumber[13]`.

Here's a minimal example:

```
\usepackage{lineno}
```

then in the body text, add the following before the code chunk:

```
{\internallinenumbers \resetlinenumber[13]
```

and then this after the code chunk:

```
}
```

With LyX (what I use for rapid LaTeX generation), I simply go to the document menu, then Settings->LaTeX Preamble and I add `\usepackage{lineno}`, click Apply, OK, and then Close.  Then in the main document before my code chunk, I insert LaTeX source by clicking the "TEX" button menu button or by pressing "Ctrl+L" on the keyboard.  Then I paste in     `{\internallinenumbers \resetlinenumber[13]`.  Finally, I place the cursor immediately after the code chunk and do the same thing. only I close the line numbering with a curly brace:  `}`.

Here is a minimal example, when the code is in place is pasted below:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{lineno}
\begin{document}
First line in main document before code chunk.

{\internallinenumbers \resetlinenumber[13]

<<CodeBlock1, highlight=TRUE, eval=FALSE, size="small">>=
x<-rnorm(10)
mean(x)
@
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For use in HTML, you can set the chunk option `class.source` to pass custom css to the output:

````
```{r class.source = c("numCode", "R", "numberLines")}
# your code
```
````

Comment: The question is about `Rnw` (Sweave), not `Rmd` (Rmarkdown).