# How to export script as PDF/text with line numbers in R?

Tags: r, pdf, export, line

I would like to perform a line-by-line review of code written using RStudio.

I have two questions:

1. How do I export the script file as a PDF/text file?
2. How do I make sure that the exported script file includes the line numbers?

Thanks!

** Update: Considering that I wasn't trying to write a report straight from the R/RStudio interface, I realized I could easily open and print the code using Notepad ++. So, here's to remembering a software that most folks probably use for their coding anyway.

Comment: After a similar question a while ago I looked in to writing a general command line tool to do just that (source code to PDF) with [libharu](http://libharu.org/). ... It's not *that* hard to quickly get something useful - I think I gave up when adding multilingual code highlighting 

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to a similar question that I had for writing a script to a text file here https://statisticsglobe.com/r-save-all-console-input-output-to-file and wanted to share for others facing the same dilemma. Unfortunately, this method does not write out the line numbers though.

# Writing currently opened R script to file

fout = "filpath/filename.txt"

cat(readChar(rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path,
file.info(rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path)$size), file = fout)

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard about [Knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/)?, and also look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27593677/putting-line-number-for-r-code-with-knitr).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know that Knitr can be a bit of a complex rabbit hole. I'll take a look into it, while keeping the thread open in case someone else has a simpler solution.