# How do you show line numbers in R Sweave chunk outputs?

Tags: r, sweave

I am writing a document in Sweave and would like to echo R code chunks in the final PDF *with* code lines. However, I cannot seem to find line numbers as a chunk option. Does anyone know how to include code lines in chunk echos?

For example, how can I get the following chunk to include the 2 line numbers (1 and 2) when the chunk is echo'd into the pdf?

```
<<echo = T, eval = T>>=
amount <- 5
5 * amount
@
```

Comment: If you're willing to switch from Sweave to knitr, you'll find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27593677/putting-line-number-for-r-code-with-knitr