# How to keep knitr style while putting line numbers in .Rnw output file?

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I have read a lot of question and relative answer but I didn't find a solution! My request is similar to this:
[Putting line number for R code with knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27593677/putting-line-number-for-r-code-with-knitr), but I want to keep the standard style of Knitr. A user, Thomas, suggest to add `language=R` to the listings options but this doesn't change the output.

A result like this:

[image: see here]

would be great! (The theme isn't relevant just the LINE number). 
I've tried to use the `render_listings()` function:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{Rstyle}{%
  fancyvrb=FALSE,escapechar=`,language=R,%
  basicstyle={\Rcolor\Sweavesize\ttfamily},%         Added \ttfamily
  backgroundcolor=\Rbackground,%
  showstringspaces=false,%
  keywordstyle=\Rcolor,%
  commentstyle={\Rcommentcolor\ttfamily\itshape},%
  %literate=                                         Removed
  alsoother={$},%
  numbers=left,                    
  numbersep=5pt, 
  alsoletter={.<-},%
  otherkeywords={!,!=,~,$,*,\&,\%/\%,\%*\%,\%\%,<-,<<-,/},%
  escapeinside={(*}{*)}}%

\begin{document}

<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
render_listings()
@

<<a, results='hold'>>=
1:2
3:4
5:6
@

<<b>>=
"test1"
"test2"
"test3"
@

\end{document}
```

Maybe I Have to modify sweavel.sty file too but I haven't idea how to do that.

Comment: The results of the code above is http://i.stack.imgur.com/T6tK0.png.
An output like that: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8f9LJ.png with line number will be fine.