# Numbering lines in code chunks in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is there a clean solution for numbering lines in code chunks in R Markdown?

There is some relevant information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27593677/putting-line-number-for-r-code-with-knitr), it solves this problem for .Rnw files, however I'm looking for a solution for .Rmd files (with HTML output). Preferably the solution would provide continuous numbering within the document, instead of starting over at each code chunk. This would allow for referencing an earlier code chunk via a line number.

I am also looking for a solution that **doesn't** require repeating the code chunk (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329685/how-to-display-line-numbers-in-rmarkdown-html-and-pdf)) since that seems error prone (inevitably there will be cases where one chunk gets updated and the other isn't).

Comment: I ended up going this route, using both html/pdf, but it's a bit more work: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179926/pandoc-markdown-to-pdf-without-cutting-off-code-block-lines-that-are-too-long

Comment: Awesome answer to this in a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37927810/1036500

Comment: @Ben Thanks, Ben :)