# Numbered Code Chunks in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is there an option I can provide to code chunks in `RMarkdown` so that it will have a `cell number` attached to the `HTML` output. Much like `Jupyter` has cell numbers.

I've seen some example with line numbering which is not what I want.

Using cell numbers is helpful when I'm discussing an `RMarkdown` `HTML` file over the phone with someone. I can ask him/her to see **cell 23**. I have a lot of `R` code, so providing section titles, while possible, is tedious.

Comment: As far as I know, Jupyter numbers cells in the order of execution, and does this for code cells only. So if two people try running the same notebook, their cell # would not necessarily agree.

In RMarkdown, you can give names to cells, but it sounds like you know this already. Does this not solve your problem?

Comment: Hi, I can  name cells, but i have so many it becomes tedious (yes, being lazy here). I am hoping Rmarkdown can automatically number the cells. We'd both be viewing the rendered html, not executing it. So rerunning and producing different cell numbers wouldnt be the issue here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution using only `CSS`. It relies on [`CSS` counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters): each new `R` chunk increments the counter (named `counter-rchunks`).

You can knit the following minimal `Rmd` file and get this result:

[image]

````
---
title: "Counter for chunks"
author: "Romain Lesur"
output: html_document
---

```{css, echo=FALSE}
body {
  counter-reset: counter-rchunks;
}

div.main-container {
  padding-left: 5em;
}

pre.r {
  counter-increment: counter-rchunks;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}

pre.r::before {
  content: 'In [' counter(counter-rchunks) ']: ';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -5em;
  color: rgb(48, 63, 159);
}
```

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

```{r head-cars}
head(cars)
```
````

You may have to adapt this solution to your `HTML` template.
You also can insert these `CSS` rules to a `.css` file and includes it in your `html_document`.

Comment: I am going to add some JavaScript to this so that the “in...” become href anchors